# How do I get an Acer Nplify 802.11b/g/n wireless card working?

Tags: wireless, acer, atheros

I use Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 on my laptop: Acer Aspire 5349.

Ubuntu 10.04 doesn't  work with LAN and WLAN. Where can I download a driver:

> Atheros WLAN AR5B91 Driver

I want `.deb` only, can that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This should work "out-of-the-box." Have you checked the BIOS settings, as suggested here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1521316.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.